# asm : @prefix followed by a number. Explain when and why this decoration exists

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering

In some of the assembly listings, the function name has a @prefix followed 
by a number. Explain when and why this decoration exists.

Comment: There are lots of different assemblies - for different architectures and ABIs. You need to be more specific, and supply an example.

Answer (score 2):

If you actually mean suffix instead of prefix, and you happen to be on windows, then the `@number` indicates it is a function using `stdcall` convention expecting the given number of bytes as arguments which will be removed from the stack by the callee (normally using a `ret number` instruction). It is important that caller and callee agree on the argument sizes otherwise the stack will become unbalanced. This is why somebody thought it may be a good idea to encode the size in the symbol itself.